# Chart.JS does not render and display a sad face icon

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, chart.js

I am using ChartJS for months, no problem rendering complex charts.
But it's about a week, maybe after last Google Chrome update, I see this sad face icon on canvas, some times, is this a known bug in Chart JS or Chrome?:

[image]

There is no error in Chrome console.

---

I just checked on Edge, it displays charts properly.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: I just faced the same problem, but in my case this happened for too large width size for a horizontally scrollable chart. Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your Chrome browser. Go to [this link](https://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history/) 
and select an earlier release and see if your problem persists.